# Floating text next to variable width image without wrapping under image?

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have two columns in a header.  On the left is an image and next to it is some header text.  I need the image and text to be side by side. Right now I'm floating both left but they won't line up side by side because I can't apply a width to either since the image can be variable width that I have no control over.

```
#header {clear:both;overflow:hidden;}
#header img {float:left;}
#header h3 {color:#000;float:left;}
```

Is it possible to use divs/css to make this work if the image can be variable width. Or should I just use a table? This also needs to work in IE 6+ (no control over that either, trust me.) thanks!

Comment: Can you post something on http://jsfiddle.net so we can really see your structure ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach
http://ghettocooler.net/2005/11/13/image-floats-without-the-text-wrap/

Float left and right instead of both left.